# Is it safe to edit Android SDK files?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I want to edit the following file so that it suits my needs. Of cause I could do extent the class or something like that. But I like to know If it is safe to do this.
E:\Program Files\Android\sdk\sources\android-22\android\view\GestureDetector.java
(Because I want to customize GestureDetector class.)

What should I do to after editing this file (like recompile the whole thing etc)?
Is this recommended?
I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: You should extends that detector in your app and use that Class in your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the file GestureDetector.java directly.

If you change the android source code, then you need to compile the source code and make a customized operating system, which is not suitable for your case.

I suggest you to make a class like **MyGestureDetector.java** which is extend from **GestureDetector.java**, then you can implement your own logic in  MyGestureDetector.java safely.

Comment: You mean if I change it here it will not work in a device with standard Android OS?

Comment: Yes, standard Android OS did't contains the change you made.